# Using List collection makes Hibernate throw stackoverflow error

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have three domain objects, one parent object with two children. The parent object has a many to one relationship with both children, and therefore both children have a collection of parent objects, while the parent has references to both children objects.

**The parent**

```
public class Parent {

    private OtherChild otherChild;
    private SomeChild someChild;

    /*Other methods and properties*/


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public SomeChild getSomeChild() {
        return this.someChild;
    }

    public void setSomeChild(SomeChild someChild) {
        this.someChild = someChild;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public OtherChild getOtherChild() {
        return this.otherChild;
    }

    public void setOtherChild(OtherChild otherChild) {
        this.otherChild = otherChild;
    }
}
```

**The children**

```
public class SomeChild {

    private List<Parent> parents;

    /*Other methods and properties*/

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "someChild")
    public List<Parent> getParents() {
        return parents;
    }

    public void setParents(List<Parent> parents) {
        this.parents = parents;
    }
}
```

I am using hibernate with JPA annotations to persist this setup to the database, but when the collection of parents in any of the children is a list, I get a stack overflow error when trying to fetch the parent(the children in the parent are both marked as `FetchType.EAGER`). When I change the fetching to `FetchType.LAZY`, fetching the parent works fine but fetching any of the children alone still causes a stack overflow error because (seeing from the SQL), **hibernate still tries to get the parent even though the parent's collection in the children is marked as lazy fetch**.

In the ordinary usage of this parent it always needs to have its children fetched so their mappings are marked as `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` in the parent object. I have tried disabling eager fetch for each of the children in turns but that only removes the error when fetching the parent but fetching any of the children still causes the SO error. The only solution I have so far is to change the type of the parents collection : `List<parent> parents` in both children from list to set. However I need to have the collection be a list for may reasons. So in short,

- Why does having a list in the child objects cause a stack overflow error
- How can I have a list of parent objects in the children and still eager fetch the children from the parent object

Comment: Why do you need to have the circular reference? It seems quote odd.

Comment: The parents are like compositions of children of two types, and both children should know which parents contain (are composed of) them

Comment: @inkalimeva Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255073/problem-with-parent-child-relation-with-hibernate)

Comment: Thanks @ankur-singhal but I do need this parent reference. Also as noted above, a set collection works but a list does not, why?